# Find Youtube Iframes Only from HTML

Tags: php, regex, iframe

I want to find iframes having src of youtube video using preg_match_all

I have tried

```
preg_match_all('#<iframe[^>]+>.*?</iframe>#is', $html, $matches);
```

but this matches all the iframes, can I have its modified version that could match the iframes only having src from youtube url.

Looking forward to some quicker response.

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try *anything*?

Comment: @Thomas I mentioned that I tried above regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex:

```
"/<iframe[^>]*src=\"[^\"]*youtu[.]?be.*<\\/iframe>/mi"
```

will match an `iframe` that contains `youtube` or `youtu.be` in the source. It should cover most cases, except the weird ones like `src="mywebsite.com/youtube/myvids"`

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me and that's what I was looking for.